# joining point and interval data

Tags: python, pandas

I have two time series I need to join:

The first one is a time series of prices
like this

```
ticker date       price 
SBUX   01/01/2012 55
```

The second time series are adjustment factors which are represented as

```
ticker start_date end_date    adjustment_factor
SBUX   01/01/1993 01/01/1994  0.015
```

How do I join these time series  together in pandas as to express adjusted prices in expression

```
adjusted_price = historical_prices * adjustment_factor
```

I understand I need to expand adjustment_factor interval time series into daily series by using date_range function. 
The issue though is that each row of adjustment time series is going to have a different date range - is there a way to to batch the conversion from interval date type for entire adjustment factor time series rather then doing it for every row.

i had figured out that i need to pivot the first point-in-time timeseries for tickers go into the columns and date into rows and for the second timeseries expand the interval into daily granularity and also pivot it (through dataframe.pivot function. by combining the two dataframes one can write function i need.

Answer (score 0):

You can simply join the dataFrame with your daily bar and use fillna(method="ffill") to forward fill the previous value.  in your example you have adjustment factors for a range.

```
#suppose sbux is an ohlc daily bar and adj is your adjustment factors  
adj  = pandas.DataFrame({"adj":pandas.Series(values,index = start_dates)})
sbux_with_adj  = sbux.join(adj)
sbux_with_adj["Adj"] =    sbux_with_adj["Adj"].fillna(method="ffill")
ohlc = sbux_with_adj[["Open","High","Low","Close"]] * sbux_with_adj["adj"]
```

I would approach adjusting with more common adjustment factors (e.g .985 for a 1.5% dividend) in the following manner:

```
sbux_with_adj  = sbux.join(adj)
sbux_with_adj["Adj"] =    sbux_with_adj["Adj"].fillna(1.0)
#now reverse cumulated adjustment.
cumulated_adj = sbux_with_adj["Adj"].cumprod().values[::-1] 
ohlc = sbux_with_adj[["Open","High","Low","Close"]] * cumulated_adj
```